# SQL: How to determine and skip the unique constraint when doing update?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm writing a SQL (Oracle) to update a table with the values in another table.  But since there is a 2 column unique constraint, the update always failed. It is something like this:

```
Table A
- A_1
- A_2
- A_3
(There is a unique constraint for A_1 + A_3 )

Table B
- B_1
- B_2
```

Here is my current sql:

```
UPDATE A a
SET a.A_1 =
    (SELECT b.B_1
    FROM B b
    WHERE a.A_2 = b.B_2
    )
AND EXISTS
    (SELECT b.B_1
    FROM B b
    WHERE a.a.A_2 = b.B_2
    )
```

I want to skip the lines that violate the unique constraint but I don't know how to do it. Please advise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an `AND NOT EXISTS` at the end, checking the constrained values against the new ones (as would be after the update):

```
...
AND NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM A checkA
    WHERE checkA.A_1 = (SELECT b.B_1 FROM B b WHERE a.A_2 = b.B_2)
    AND checkA.A_3 = a.A_3
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got the idea. I'm trying it right now. But I'm seeing an issue of running too long time. The B table is very big. Do you have any idea to improve it? Thank you!

Comment: Forgive my naivety but I would start by looking at why you are doing an update but arbitrarily ignoring rows because they would fail a constraint. In my book the fact that it would fail a constraint says you're doing something wrong in the first place...

Comment: Your point makes sense to me, too. This is actually a data backfilling from a table to another table. The B table is a middleware forwarding the data to the A table. Now we are merging it to A table. Since we have added some new features to A which is not going through B, there could be some conflict data between A and B. This is caused our new feature's defect. We are going to ingore it for now.

Comment: Gotcha. I can't think of anything of the top of my head to make it any faster, but you can check the output of an `EXPLAIN` and see if that helps.

Comment: You can check if you have an index on B(B_2,B_1)

Comment: Using MERGE statement would be more appropriate in this case. Check the site for MERGE usage scenario.